# Catch AWS's TooManyRequestsException when using Pyathena

Tags: amazon-athena, pyathena

I want to use [Pyathena](https://pypi.org/project/PyAthena/) to connect to and query an AWS Athena database. Given, that Athena has a hard limit of consecutive running queries (see [AWS Athena > Service Quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html)), and my application will be running on hundreds of parallel-running worker instances, it can be assumed that in extreme cases a query will fail due to too many queries already being processed/queued. According to the Athena documentation, a `TooManyRequestsException` error is to be expected in those instances.

I want to handle that specific edge case gracefully in my Python code, but I cannot find any indication as to how this `TooManyRequestsException` error will propagate. Pyathena's `error` module doesn't expose an exception with this name, and I couldn't find a reference to this specific error case in the Pyathena documentation.

How can I catch that exception?